# How to prevent array locations from being converted to string when Json encoded and force output as int

Tags: php, json, variables, int

I have a PHP script which sends data into MCU (IOT) chip in an encoded JSON document.
Mine problem is that when I use `json_encode($Output[$line])`
with `$Output[$line]` containing nested array.
Example of the Output array content printed by `print_r()`

```
(
  [0] => 5
  [1] => Array
  (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [3] => Array
    (
      [0] => 0
      [1] => 1
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
      [0] => 0
      [1] => 0
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
      [0] => 1
      [1] => 1
    )

    [6] => Array
    (
      [0] => 12345
      [1] => 222222
    )

    [7] => Array
    (
      [0] => 
      [1] => 
    )

    [8] => Array
    (
      [0] => 
      [1] => 
    )

    [9] => Array
    (
      [0] => 
      [1] => 
    )

    [10] => Array
    (
      [0] => 
      [1] => 
    )

    [11] => Array
    (
      [0] => 
      [1] => 
    )
  )
)
```

Where nested array in a first position results in:

```
{"0":1,"1":1,"3":["0","1"],"4":[0,0],"5":["1","1"],"6":["12345","222222"],"7":[null,null],"8":[null,null],"9":[null,null],"10":[null,null],"11":[null,null],"2":2}
```

With first placeholder being named with string containing zero, rather than being on a position zero.

What I would like to get is:

```
{1,1,2,[0,1],[0,0],[1,1],[12345,222222],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]}
```

Stage one with placeholders sorted, by initializing array fully prior to assigning data:

```
$Output[$line]=array(0,0,0,array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0));
```

Now on output:

```
[1,1,2,["0","1",0],[0,0,0],["1","1",0],["12345","222222",0],[null,null,0],[null,null,0],[null,null,0],[null,null,0],[null,null,0]]
```

Now just a matter of how to force the content into int rather then a string containing the number

Comment: Array values need to be numerically sequential to become an array.  You would either need to make sure it's in sequence( i.e. not 0,1,3 but 0,1,2) or use `array_values()`.

Comment: Yes, and also this `"3":["0","1"],"4":[0,0]` indicates that some values are integers and some are strings, which is not your problem now but may be later.

Comment: How are you building this array?  You can probably fix it there.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: That is one of mine problems which I am trying to avoid

Comment: the array gets values from database with possition 1 being number of arrays generated and 2 calculated after all the rest was generated

Comment: Well, that's probably where you need to fix it but haven't shown that code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Solved. 
First problem was solved by initializing array including all the nested arrays to initial values, so that placeholders are already assigned

```
$Output[$line]=array(0,0,0,array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0),array(0,0,0));
```

The problem of int as string was solved by forcing last assignment as int eg: 
```
$Output[$line][$i]=(int)$snimac["vyska"];
```